# Bootstrap Row Negative Margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why does Bootstrap row element have `margin-left: -15px` and `margin-right: -15px`? When a `row` element is nested into a `col-**-*` element, it sticks out even on their official site. What is the best way to make a nested `row` not stick out from its parent `col-**-*`?

[Link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2yux.png)

Comment: This article should help [The Subtle Magic Behind Why the Bootstrap 3 Grid Works](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works)

Comment: This is so you don't get double padding on the inside of your `.container`, because `.container`'s have 15px padding on the left and right, just like the `col-`'s.

Comment: @dhiman The link is behind a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite bootstrap css rules by calling your custom stylesheet file after bootstrap's.

```
.row {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you want to apply this only to rows nested into col-*

```
[class*=”col-”] .row {
  margin: 0;
}
```